# spring boot jpa mysql query performing slow

Tags: spring-boot, performance, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have flow which fetches some data from the table using simple query(no joins). I triggered two requests one at `t` and other at `t+10` minutes but both response came at same time for 1st request it took 20 mins for second request it took 10 mins. So I checked that query it is taking more time (about 20 mins) but same query I ran through mysql console taking 110 seconds. How can I improve the performance

Code to fetch data from db:

```java
@Query(nativeQuery = true,
    value = "select id, expiry_date as expiryDate "
        + "from checkout_extension "
        + "where expiry_date between :date and :nextDate",
    countQuery = "select count(id) "
        + "from checkout_extension "
        + "where expiry_date between :date and :nextDate")
Page<CheckoutExpiryNotification> findByExpiryDateBetween(
    final Date date, final Date nextDate, final Pageable pageable);
```

The same query taking very less time through mysql console. How can I improve performance?

Comment: Try to create an index for expiry_date. what is the total record count?

Comment: @ManishKumar okay, why is there difference in performance for the same query when I run through spring boot code and mysql console and the difference is very significant. total record count is 5 crore.

Comment: 50M that's huge, the application itself adds the latency(fetching + converting to entity object) and then processes it. try to create indexing on date or create sharding.

Comment: 50M data in total, query is fetching around 500 records from that table.

Comment: right.. but it is being search among 50M

Comment: @ManishKumar can you make me understand then why simple mysql query in the console is much more faster than this? also is there any other method to fasten it up other than indexing.

Comment: @SankethKini Consider the console to be 'next door' rather than a 4 bus/train/taxi stops from you.  Did you ever use TRACERT to determine how many computers might be involved to connect to your application?